# Как объединить таблицы по подстроке?

Tags: python, pandas, join, анализ-данных, обработка-данных

Пытаюсь сделать объединение двух фреймов по некоторому условию, но не пойму как это сделать.

DataFrame: my

```
        Operator    phone                   Date      Year  Month   Weekday
0   Иванов Иван   89101054581; 88312617706  2021-01-01  2021    1   4
1   Петров Роман  89307167823               2021-01-08  2021    1   4
3   Иванов Иван   89200239899; 89519012568  2021-01-11  2021    1   0
4   Петров Роман  89307167823               2021-01-20  2021    1   4
```

DataFrame: ph

```
    Date2              Year   Month Кто звонил  Куда звонил Статус звонка
0   2021-01-04 12:10:47 2021    1    89101054581    4462    БЕЗ ОТВЕТА
1   2021-01-06 15:05:21 2021    1    89101054581    4459    БЕЗ ОТВЕТА
2   2021-01-11 8:03:13  2021    1    88312617706    4458    БЕЗ ОТВЕТА
3   2021-01-21 8:03:36  2021    1    89200239899    4457    ОТВЕЧЕН
```

Результирующий фрейм:

```
    Operator        phone                   Date      Year   Month  
 0   Иванов Иван      89101054581; 88312617706  2021-01-01  2021    1   

Date2                 Кто звонил Куда звонил Статус звонка
2021-01-04 12:10:47  89101054581    4462        БЕЗ ОТВЕТА
2021-01-06 15:05:21  89101054581    4459        БЕЗ ОТВЕТА
2021-01-11 8:03:13   88312617706    4458        БЕЗ ОТВЕТА

     Operator       phone                   Date      Year      Month
1    Иванов Иван    89200239899; 89519012568    2021-01-11  2021    1

Date2                Кто звонил  Куда звонил Статус звонка
2021-01-21 8:03:36  89200239899     4457      ОТВЕЧЕН
```

Если один из номеров в столбце `my['phone']` равен номеру телефона из столбца `ph['Кто звонил']` и при этом `my['Month'] = ph['Month']`, то должна получится таблица как на картинке, фрейм - `Sum_table`

Просто сделать concat по полю `my['phone']`, что-то типа:

```
result = pd.concat([my2, ph2], axis=1, join="inner")
```

не работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

решение:

```
res = (my
       .assign(x=my["phone"].str.split(";\s*"))
       .explode("x")
       .merge(ph.assign(x=ph["Кто звонил"].astype(str)))
       .drop(columns="x"))
```

результат:

```
In [316]: res
Out[316]:
      Operator                     phone        Date  Year  Month  Weekday                Date2   Кто звонил  Куда звонил Статус звонка
0  Иванов Иван  89101054581; 88312617706  2021-01-01  2021      1        4  2021-01-04 12:10:47  89101054581         4462    БЕЗ ОТВЕТА
1  Иванов Иван  89101054581; 88312617706  2021-01-01  2021      1        4  2021-01-06 15:05:21  89101054581         4459    БЕЗ ОТВЕТА
2  Иванов Иван  89101054581; 88312617706  2021-01-01  2021      1        4   2021-01-11 8:03:13  88312617706         4458    БЕЗ ОТВЕТА
3  Иванов Иван  89200239899; 89519012568  2021-01-11  2021      1        0   2021-01-21 8:03:36  89200239899         4457       ОТВЕЧЕН
```